# Update redux-store before ReactDOM.render(...)

Tags: reactjs, redux

Is there a way to update the Redux store before the ReactDOM.render(...) is runned?
Something like `store.dispatch(...).then(() => ReactDOM.render(...))`

Or a way to just replace the entire "state" of the store?

I am making an API with React components that is used inside another application with another framework, Dojo. Because of this we are using ReactDOM.render(...) and ReactDOM.unmountCompoentAtNode(...) when the component should appear/disappear.

So in the API, I am reusing the redux store, since it is not deleted from the memory/RAM even though a React component is unmounted via `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(...)`. If I did not reuse the store, but made a new one every time the React component should render, the actions where "fetched by the Redux store" more and more times. Because of this I would like to ensure that I get to refresh the Redux store before I mount the component again.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the rendered state should depend on the redux store, have you seen [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) ?

One way is to have a show a spinner when the API endpoint is being reached out to.
After setting the state from the API response, go ahead and show the real component.

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching the solution in the wrong way. For this use case, we have `life cycle methods` in components

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

In this code I am rendering `App` component, to solve your problem I'll use `componentDidMount` life cycle method of `App` and from there I'll dispatch the API call.

```
class App {
    componentDidMount() {
        dispatch(MY_ACTION)
    }
    render() {
        return (<h1>dummy</h1>)
    }
}
```

For `hooks` based functional component, you need to use `useEfect`

```
const App = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(MY_ACTION)
    }, [])

    return (<h1>dummy</h1>)
}
```

Comment: I updated my question so you can see more of my problem.
I do now know if this will ensure that the redux store is updated? What about the time untill the componentDidMount() fires? I think the old Redux state still will be there, since I am reusing the Redux store.

Comment: Well, in this case you can dispatch an action from `constructor` to clear your store.